# I've completely rewrote one of my deleted questions to lift a curse. What to do?

Tags: support

I'm talking about this:

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/77710/adapting-military-tactics-to-plasma-rifles-ignore-this

**Who can look it up to judge, whether it's worthy of undeleting, and where do, deleted, but re-edited questions go?**

*Also, I'd like to remind Community, that Android Hell is a real place where you'll be really sent, at the first sign of disobedience.*

Comment: Why not just put the question into the sandbox?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Remember the curse, here's it's effect: "Ain't you gonna post questions here, till you fixed the lower quality ones." -The system essential y said this to me.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T So, you suggest to make a duplicate, post it in sandbox along with this link?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Alright.

Comment: The sandbox sounds like a good idea.  That way everybody can help you with the question, not just the smaller group of people who can see deleted posts.

Comment: I had that “curse” in [SuperUser.se].  They are a vicious lot over there.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question to ask on meta and am disappointed to see several downvotes.  You might not like the question on main that Redacted is asking about, but asking here how to improve a post is one of the things that meta is for.

Answer (score 3):

That question was deleted by the “roomba” because of the [last reason shown on the help page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

If it’s edited soon after closing, it doesn’t get deleted and can be re-opened easily.

Normally, the question being deleted with no answers, there’s no reason to rework it under the same ID but a new post is just fine. The auto-block algorithm is kept secret and may even be changed from time to time, but I do recall that deleting low-scoring posts doesn’t help (I got a notice to that affect when deleting a post).

Anyway, once you have a “good” version in the sandbox, one of us will help you get the post undeleted and, if necessary, paste the revised text into it.

Good luck, and thanks for sticking with it!